# Is it possible to create widgets in NativeScript or React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, nativescript

I am interested in learning React Native or NativeScript.

I am curious to know that if it is possible to create Widgets in either of these?

I searched online a lot about this but I could not find any solid information about this yet.

Any information on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Regards

Ayyaz

Comment: With react-native, no. This is not a feature in the most recent release, there was a feature request opened a while ago that you could upvote - https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/android-home-screen-widget

Comment: great and what about nativescript?

Comment: I believe in nativescript it is possible. Pretty unfamiliar with the framework though

Comment: I replied to your post on the NS forums - https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/is-it-possible-to-create-native-widgets-using-nativescript/2319/2?u=pete.k